# How to install MacBuntu on an Ubuntu minimal install?

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, themes, gui, macbuntu

I've tried going for Cinnamon install however the process failed. [Discussion here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141069/install-gui-in-non-pae-12-04-core).

I want to try a different approach.

Thus my question is, how do I install [MacBuntu](http://sourceforge.net/projects/macbuntu/) or MAC-4-Lin right onto a Ubuntu minimal environment.

Comment: tried going through lxde, but it looks aweful! any alternatives available???? its not hep under unity/Gnome anymore!!

Comment: 1500+ views... still no response... Infact this was the same question i was thinking to ask with the same verbatim... I am eager to know the same as having mac4lin on 12.04 looks so crippled !

Comment: Still looking for an answer Z9iT?

Comment: pff elementary OS is fine. I dunno what all this nitpicking on themes is about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Install McMojave theme in 18.04 and later

1. Download the McMojave theme package from [McMojave - Gnome.look.org](https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1275087/) to your `~/Downloads` directory. Click the download button and choose one of the following four McMojave theme packages.

   - Mojave-light: light version
   - Mojave-light-solid: light version without transparence
   - Mojave-dark: dark version
   - Mojave-dark-solid: dark version without transparence
2. Run the following commands

   ```
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool gtk2-engines-murrine gtk2-engines-pixbuf plank  
   cd ~/Downloads/
   tar xf Mojave-light.tar.xz # replace Mojave-light.tar.xz with the theme that you downloaded
   mkdir ~/.themes
   mv Mojave-light ~/.themes/
   ```
3. Launch Tweaks from the Dash and change to Applications theme appearance to *Mojave-light*.
4. Download the macOS [Mojave CT icons](https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1210856/). Once again pick any icon style and save the package into your `~/Downloads` directory.
5. Run these commands to install the macOS Mojave CT icons:

   ```
   tar xf Mojave-CT-light.tar.xz
   mkdir ~/.icons
   mv Mojave-CT-light ~/.icons/
   ```
6. Change the icons to macOS Mojave theme in the Tweaks application.
7. Download the [macOS cursor set](https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1148748/) package. Pick any cursor style and save the package into your `~/Downloads` directory.
8. Run these commands to install it:

   ```
   unzip -qq macOS\ Cursor\ Set.zip
   mv macOS\ Cursor\ Set ~/.icons/
   ```
9. Change the cursor to *macOS Cursor Set* in the Tweaks application.
10. Download the [Mojave wallpaper](https://www.reddit.com/r/wallpapers/comments/e4fz6s/a_more_purpleish_version_of_the_mac_os_mojave/). Change  the wallpaper from *Settings* → *Background* → *Picture* tab → select a picture → press *Select* button (in 18.04) or *Settings* → *Background* → *Add Picture* (in 20.04).
11. Open Plank from the Dash. At this point you should see the macOS panel at the bottom of your desktop. Press the left <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>key, and right-click the bottom macOS panel to open up *Preferences*. Customize the macOS panel to fit your desired look and feel. If you wish to take yet another step further install the optional [macOS Plank theme](https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1248226/).
12. Remove the default GNOME dock panel.

    ```
    sudo apt remove gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock
    ```
13. Configure the Plank application to start automatically after reboot.

    [image: Add Plank to Startup Applications]

<sub>**Source:** revised from [How to install macOS theme on Ubuntu 20.04 Focal](https://web.archive.org/web/20200512204317/https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-macos-theme-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux)</sub>

---

MacBuntu has been discontinued, and it has been replaced by the [MBuntu Transformation Pack](http://www.noobslab.com/2014/11/mbuntu-macbuntu-1410-transformation.html) for Ubuntu 14.04-17.04. The MBuntu Transformation Pack transforms the default Unity or GNOME desktop environment into a desktop environment theme which resembles Mac OS X Yosemite.

---

The [Themes Collection by NoobsLab](https://launchpad.net/~noobslab/+archive/ubuntu/themes?field.series_filter=utopic) PPA has an interesting selection of themes for Ubuntu, including MBuntu. The same PPA has a selection of theme packages resembling MAC OS X Lion for Ubuntu 12.04-18.04. To add this PPA to your software sources, open the terminal and run the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/themes
sudo apt-get update
```

Then you can install any of five different MBuntu packages or any of nine different Mac OS X theme packages for Ubuntu 12.04 from the Ubuntu Software Center.

**Features**

- Themes are shiny, smooth, fast, and look like the latest Mac
- Mac Boot Splash auto configuration
- Mac theme for LightDM-webkit auto configuration
- Separate GTK themes for each desktop (Unity, Gnome Classic, Linux Mint)
- Latest icon set
- Auto set themes and icons script

Comment: Answer relevant in year 2020: 
Resource1: https://linuxcool.ru/en/macbuntu-20-04-or-how-to-make-ubuntu-look-like-macos/
Resource2: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-macos-theme-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux