# PPA for the Macbuntu theme in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, themes, ppa, macbuntu

Does the PPA still work for the Macbuntu theme in Ubuntu 20.04? If not what happened to the old Macbuntu theme that was compatible with earlier Ubuntu releases? Has the Macbuntu theme become a component of a different OS, or how is it still possible to install a Macbuntu theme or transformation pack in Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: The “Macbuntu” theme works [up to 18.10](https://launchpad.net/~noobslab/+archive/ubuntu/macbuntu) and does not seem to have had much movement in the last two years. If you would like an Apple-like Ubuntu, you might really enjoy [ElementaryOS](https://elementary.io/).

Answer (score 2):

The PPA for the Macbuntu transformation pack for Ubuntu (ppa:noobslab/macbuntu) works in Ubuntu 18.04 and earlier, but it hasn't been updated for Ubuntu 20.04. In Ubuntu 20.04 follow the instructions in the accepted answer to [How to install MacBuntu on an Ubuntu minimal install?](https://askubuntu.com/q/150311/). They are up-to-date for Ubuntu 20.04.

To add the [Macbuntu PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Enoobslab/+archive/ubuntu/macbuntu) to your software sources in Ubuntu 18.04 and earlier run the following commands.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/macbuntu
sudo apt-get update
apt-cache search macbuntu-os
```

Results of `apt-cache search macbuntu-os` in Ubuntu 18.04:

```
macbuntu-os-icons-v1804 - MacBuntu Icons & cursors uploaded on NoobsLab.com PPA
macbuntu-os-ithemes-v1804 - MacBuntu Themes available on NoobsLab.com PPA
macbuntu-os-plank-theme-v1804 - These themes are intended to use with Macbuntu by NoobsLab.com
```

Comment: Thank You. I have Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.